# MySQL Update Incremented (Not Auto-Incremented) Column Values

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table with 4 columns, one of which is called "order". "Order" is not auto-incremented, but another column, "mapping_id" is auto-incremented. The other columns include "quiz_id" and "question_id".

[image: Image of Table Structure]

I want to change all the values of "order" to go in the same ascending order as the question_id field. My application only sorts based on this "order" column, so the only way I can re-sort is to edit the values in this column.

What I want to know is how to write an update query to change all the values of "order" to go in an ascending number sequence. I thought of just matching the value of "order" to that of "question_id", but question_id starts at 2 instead of 1, and "order" must begin at 1. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like the following might do what you are looking for.  It will assign incrementing values to `order` based on the `question_id` ordering:

```
select @ordval := 0;
update thetable set `order` = 
        (select @ordval := @ordval + 1) order by question_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set order = question_id -1 . This way it will start at 1. You might get some holes either way if you have holes in question_id, but if you don't have holes this does the trick.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET `order` = question_id - 1
```